# Method does not overide method from superclass error in android

Tags: android

am trying to pass the array as argument in the onlistitemclick method but it says like Method does not overide the the method from super class.below is the code..please give me some suggestion

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> list = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : list) {

            mylist.add(packageInfo.packageName);

        }
 new LoadApplications().execute();
    }
}
  @Override//here is the error
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l,View v, int position, long id,ArrayList<String> mylist) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
      //  PACKAGENAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
        Uri packageUri = Uri.parse(mylist.get(position));
        Intent uninstallIntent =
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, packageUri);
        startActivity(uninstallIntent);
}
```

Comment: We need to see your class declaration, you probably miss some "implement"

Comment: It's basically telling you there isn't a method of the same name and arguments in the superclass - what class are you extending? Where does the argument `ArrayList<String> mylist` in the method signature come from?

Answer (score 1):

The signature of method is as below

```
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

Also note that this method is not defined in the `Activity.java` but only in `ListActivity.java` and `ListFragment.java`

You need to check the type of class your class extends. Also note that an extra parameter `ArrayList<String> mylist` is being included in the code you have shown, this is not as per the signature of methods as described in  ListActivity and ListFragment.

Hope that helps